# PHP machine learning

Tags: php, machine-learning, foreach, dataset

I'm using [this](https://github.com/ziobru/php-ml) library to implement a basic machine learning in a project. I'm trying to loop over an array of teams of a competition and then use every single match as a label for a prediction about a percentage of success.
I'm training the script and all it seem to be ok in this part, but when I try to output the result of the prediction, there will be displayed only the first two team of the file. What I'm doing wrong with the loop?

This is the output of the machine learning library

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["Frosinone Calcio"]=> float(0.413733) ["AC Chievo Verona"]=> float(0.586267) } }
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["Frosinone Calcio"]=> float(0.58545) ["AC Chievo Verona"]=> float(0.41455) } }
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["Frosinone Calcio"]=> float(0.58545) ["AC Chievo Verona"]=> float(0.41455) } }
```

But I expect something like this:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["Frosinone Calcio"]=> float(0.413733) ["AC Chievo Verona"]=> float(0.586267) } }
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["Juventus"]=> float(0.58545) ["Milan"]=> float(0.41455) } }
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["Sassuolo"]=> float(0.58545) ["Empoli"]=> float(0.41455) } }
// ecc...
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Phpml\Classification\SVC;
use Phpml\SupportVectorMachine\Kernel;
use Phpml\Dataset\ArrayDataset;

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('serie_a.json'),true);

$classifier = new SVC(
    Kernel::LINEAR, // $kernel
    1.0,            // $cost
    3,              // $degree
    null,           // $gamma
    0.0,            // $coef0
    0.001,          // $tolerance
    100,            // $cacheSize
    true,           // $shrinking
    true            // $probabilityEstimates, set to true
);

foreach($data['matches'] as $match){
   $homeTeam = $match['homeTeam']['name'];
   $awayTeam = $match['awayTeam']['name'];
   #$matchday = $match['matchday'];
   #$oldDate = new DateTime($match['utcDate']);
   #$date = $oldDate->format('Y-m-d');
   $labels = ["$homeTeam", "$awayTeam"];
}

$samples = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1]];

$classifier->train($samples, $labels);

echo '<pre>'.var_dump($classifier->predictProbability([[1, 0]])).'</pre>';
echo '<pre>'.var_dump($classifier->predictProbability([[1, 1]])).'</pre>';
echo '<pre>'.var_dump($classifier->predictProbability([[0, 1]])).'</pre>';
//$classifier->predictProbability([[3, 2], [1, 5]]);
// return [
//   ['a' => 0.349833, 'b' => 0.650167],
//   ['a' => 0.922664, 'b' => 0.0773364],
// ]
?>
```